# HY090 - Invalid string or buffer length (0)

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to insert data to a table by using .sql file with many insert statements.

Statement looks like below:

```
INSERT [dbo].[table_name] ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7], [col8], [col9], [col10], [col11], [col12], [col13], [col14], [col15], [col16], [col17], [col18], [col19], [col20], [col21], [col22], [col23], [col24], [col25]) VALUES (N'01111', N'SOME RANDOM NAME', N'ABCDE', N'Times', N'ABCD', N'0#aa:', N'06', N'SM', N'123 Cerfdty', N'NULL', N'SM', N'NULL', N'NULL', N'000', N'o2:aq', N'wef0', N'000', N'xx:xx', N'xxxxx', N'ZM', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
```

Each statement is executed individually and committed after that by reading the file.

But after completing around 240 insert statements, I get the following error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

- Python: 3
- pyodbc: 4.0.17
- OS: Windows 10
- DB: Microsoft SQL Server
- driver:
  ['SQL Server',
  'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
  'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
  'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']

I tried with above drives to connect. But i get the same error with all driver options. I am running in my local machine to connect Microsoft SQL server.

When I started reading about this issue, I found documents under Microsoft which states:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-2017

HY090 | Invalid string or buffer length | (DM) The value in BufferLength was less than 0. (See the description of the SQL_DESC_DATA_PTR field in SQLSetDescField.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlsetdescfield-function?view=sql-server-2017

Some Binding parameter needs to be set to clear the buffer but I am not seeing any information available or options available to use in pyodbc i think.

I maybe clearly diverted from the original cause of this issue.

Kindly assist me with this issue.

```
try:
    with open(filename,'r') as sqlfile:
        sql_query = ''
        count =0
        for line in sqlfile:
            if 'GO' in line:
                cursor.execute(sql_query)
                sql_query = ''
                conn.commit()
                count = count +1
                print(count)
            elif 'PRINT' in line:
                display = line.split("'")[1]
                print(display)
            else:
                sql_query = sql_query + line 
        sqlfile.close()
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: pyodbc 4.0.17 is rather old. Can you try using pyodbc 4.0.25 and see if it works any better?

Comment: Hello Gord, I just upgraded pyodbc to newer version and tried running again. I get the same failure

Comment: was this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'GO' as it should not be necessary in this context.